# Change main file used by installed jspm package

Tags: command-line-interface, jspm

Jspm override which main file to use

When I do `jspm install select2` I get the following auto-generated file at `jspm_packages/github/select2/select2@4.0.3.js`

```
define(["github:select2/select2@4.0.3/js/select2"], function(main) {
  return main;
});
```

I would instead like it to use `"github:select2/select2@4.0.3/js/select2.full"` How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, [got it](http://jspm.io/docs/installing-packages.html)

`jspm install select2 --override "{ main: 'js/select2.full'}"`